# Trying to put together a packaging list from a spreadsheet in excel

Tags: excel

[Excel Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSa5s.png)

In column A I have a list of order numbers. In columns B-F I have the different products and the number of orders each have placed for the product. How do I make it so that when I type in the order value into I1, it will return all cells with values into the cells below?

I believe it is an array that i need but not positive. This is just an example, I am trying to do this on a larger scale.

Comment: do a search on here, there are similar questions with answers...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula, it should help or at least give you an idea.

```
  =INDEX($B$2:$F$6,MATCH($I$1,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH($I2,$B$1:$F$1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it will be like this:

In I2 your formula is

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0)&":F"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0))),0))
```

In I3 your formula is

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0)&":F"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0)))*(A1:F1<>I2),0))
```

In I4 your formula should be

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0)&":F"&MATCH(I1,A:A,0)))*(A1:F1<>I2)*(A1:F1<>I3),0))
```

And there it goes...

For each cell below you will need to repeat the multiplication "(A1:F1<>I*x*)" with every cell above, because it evaluates an array which will compare to the others and return the next true result that isn't any of the colors above neither is a color without value.

Every of those formulas are array formula (confirm them with ctrl+shift+enter). You probably know how to get the values in J, but just in case, it's:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$7,MATCH($I$1,A:A,0),MATCH($I2,$A$1:$F$1,0))
```

PS: my Excel is in portuguese so my arguments separator is ";", I did change them for "," here in this comment. Just in case the formula doesn't work for you, try to look for some ";" I may have missed, also pay some attention to the $$ because I didn't lock the I1 reference properly, still I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I ended up going with a vlookup then set a quick macro to run auto-filtering based off conditional formatting. It was the cleanest way i could find to work with the large amount of data I had.